# What is up with questions at 3:00 AM?

Tags: discussion

So I sunk a few hours yesterday into looking at how questions score as a function of when they were asked. You can read the primary report of what I found [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/questions-on-the-mathematica-stack-exchange-part-2.html#main-content).

Probably the most interesting part is this graph:

[image: question-time-graph]

Here's that laid out in a grid:

[image: grid of times]

That's a break down of average score for a question as a function of when in the day it was asked, plotted for the four timezones (where for each timezone, t, the span is [UTC+t, UTC+t+2) with the most users (of course, this is only for the users who have tagged their location).

The base time there is UTC-4, so UTC+10 times need to have 14 added to then, UTC -6 needs two hours subtracted from it, etc.

For context, here's the aggregate graph of *all* questions (with scores rescaled between 0 and 1) with the rescaled plot of question posting times -- a stand-in for site interaction, I figured:

[image: questions-with-time].

I noted three primary peaks, there, one at ~18:00, one at ~20:00 and one at ~3:00, all UTC-4, with many smaller sub-peaks as well. We can then try to align where these peaks come from, timezone wise, assuming the ~9,000 (I think) users with locations tagged are a decent sample of the whole population.

Here's the same with the numbers scaled down to the score scale (that interaction curve is basically just scale-less) and the times shifted and for Europe (UTC+2), which my data suggests is where most users of the site come from:

[image: europe-plot]

One weird thing that appears out of this is that the primary peak scoring times are for ~2:00-6:00 AM at the respective time zones (the UTC+10 peaks are more numerous, but there are many fewer UTC+10 users). What could be going on with questions there?

My guess was that it was some combination of committed users who were too tired to answer their interesting questions themselves and people with questions they'd tried to solve all day but simply couldn't. But this seems like weak speculation to me and there must be something I've missed.

Comment: I find the graph you present too small and too busy to me to draw any conclusions at all from it. Also, I find it too hard to keep in mind your time zone transformation while I am studying the plot. So I'm afraid your effort is lost on me.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'd be happy to split it up into the timezone components if that'd interest you. I'll also add one other graph from that post that might provide more context, too.

Comment: I don't think you should make the effort just for me. If several others indicate they would be interested in the additional work, than you might consider it.

Comment: @m_goldberg sounds good. I think the plot makes more sense when you consider it in the context of the entire population (the extra graph I just added). It's still hard to say what exactly is going on, though, and there are obviously additive effects across the time zones, but the early morning spikes really jumped out at me as a surprise. Like I would have expected dips then, not spikes.

Comment: I have to agree with m_goldberg, some of the graphs look like you're cramming too much in a small space.

Comment: @J.M. an entirely reasonable critique. These things are always easier to read if you made were the one that made them. I'll try to separate that first one out, as I think that's the most interesting of the plots.

Comment: @J.M. added a better comparison. Unfortunately UTC+8 (Manila's timezone per Google) is too noisy to get anything really to compare.

Comment: You don't need to specifically cater for my timezone. :D But I appreciate that you're now using a grid; now maybe you can try making the y-axes the same in all of them...

Comment: @J.M. easily done (and it is) now that I've recomputed my timezones.